# On Checkbox selection, update database using listview fields

Tags: c#, listview, webforms

I'm using a listview to show various columns/rows from a database. One of these columns is an "id" and is hidden for the user. Another one of the columns is a checkbox that the user can click to "pick up a task".

```
<asp:ListView ID="listViewDataSource" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id,intFrmID" SelectedIndex="0">
```

Then in the ItemTemplate:

```
<tr runat="server">
<td class="hidden">
   <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' /> 
</td>
<td>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="check" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="check1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Checked='<%# (bool)Eval("bitIsPickedUp") %>' />
  <asp:Label ID="CheckLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("bitIsPickedUp") %>' />
</td>
```

When someone clicks that checkbox, I want to create a new record in the db. In order to do that, I need to get the hidden "id" field and pass it to my function that adds the record.

```
    protected void check1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //in here, I want to get the id, which I should be able to use listViewDataSource.SelectedDataKey but the datakey has one value and it's not correct, makes me think it's being cached somehow?
        var datakey = listViewDataSource.SelectedDataKey;
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("bitIsPickedUp");


    }
```

I'm not super familiar with web forms and using ListView, so help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an ````<asp:HiddenField />```` ?

Comment: @JohnPete22 Nope, just hiding it.

Comment: Is your ListView being dynamically created? Meaning, it needs to be data-bound again on PostBacks.  Just a thought.

Comment: @JohnPete22 yes, it's being dynamically created.

Comment: To verify that you need to re-bind... Debug, and then on PostBack look at the ````listViewDataSource```` either in the Immediate Window or by hovering over the variable when you get to that line of code. Look at the ````Items```` collection and see if it actually has any items. If not, you know you need to rebind.

Comment: @JohnPete22, it has three items in the items collection.

Comment: So you have items, but none are selected.  Another good tid bit is to add some null checks.. ````if (item != null)```` .  But it sounds like you are losing your selected item.

Comment: And your other logic should be......````if (listViewDataSource.Items.Count > 0)```` -- not selected items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that you might be losing your SelectedItem on PostBacks, you have a few issues with your code. So I'll just add a few things here....

```
protected void check1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //this is null...
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)listViewDataSource.SelectedValue;

    if (item == null) {
        if (listViewDataSource.Items.Count > 0) {
            item = (ListViewItem)listViewDataSource.Items[0];
        }
    }

    if (item != null) {
        //this returns a checkbox = true value and upon expanding has lots of data that's not super helpful, except maybe the clientID which has the row number
        CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;

        // add NULL CHECK

        //FindControl doesn't seem to find anything, gets null
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("bitIsPickedUp");

        // add NULL CHECK

        if (chk.Checked) {
            string intId = ((Label)item.FindControl("id")).Text;
            bool success = Int32.TryParse(intId, out int id);
            if (success) {
                GoQuote.InsertIntoGoList(id, 16073);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // log error -- execute additonal logic
    }
```

Comment: I also added some comments for 'NULL check' -- as anytime you have to find a control or cast a control, it's always a good idea to make sure you have an object.

Comment: I've read so many posts about how to make this work that it's all blending together. What I'm seeing now is: listViewDataSource.SelectedIndex is 0; listViewDataSource.SelectedValue is 1, and listViewDataSource.SelectedDataKey returns a datakey object that has the ("Id", 1)...which isn't the actual id, the id is 158004. Maybe I set something up wrong on the aspx page?

Comment: I think you need to show the HTML for the ListView in your original post, it might help shed some light.

Comment: So I update the original ask. I know the code in check1_CheckedChanged wasn't right, I was trying to get _something_ in there to work. It now looks like the DataKeyNames isn't working how I'd expect it to.

Comment: I've never used multiple keys in the ````DataKeyNames```` -- only used one value that is unique and can then be used to look-up the object/class/data I need to get.

Comment: thanks for all your help! MS magic, sigh. I think I'm going to try a solution that doesn't use listview.